# Stuck in an infinite loop iterating through properties in a C# class

Tags: c#, reflection, foreach

I'm iterating through the properties of a C# class to compare the values with another instance.  The concept seems simple and will work for what I'm trying to do.  However, my foreach loop never stops.  It just continues to loop through the class and results in a `StackOverflowException`.  I'm at a loss with this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static Object ORIGINALRECORD { get; set; }

protected String DirtySets() 
{
    String sDirtySets = "";

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (ORIGINALRECORD.GetType() == this.GetType())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(property.Name);
            object originalValue = ORIGINALRECORD.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(ORIGINALRECORD, null);
            object newValue = property.GetValue(this, null);
            if (!object.Equals(originalValue, newValue))
            {
                sDirtySets = (sDirtySets == "" ? "" : sDirtySets + ",") + property.Name + "=?";
            }    
        }
    }

    return "SET "+sDirtySets;
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same property over and over again or is it the full list of peroperties then starting again? Can you show some of the output of Debug.WriteLine?

Comment: The `StackOverflowException` is an indication that you are performing an infinite recursion, not iterating an infinite loop. However, I'm unable to spot the recursion in your code.

Comment: Not related, but you can do the `if` outside the `foreach`, since the types being compared never change.

Comment: Is the method DirtySets called in one of your properties? And also, what type of object is stored in the static property ORIGINALRECORD?

Comment: If you simple debug and have the StackOverflowException thrown in your face, you can see the repeating pattern, and know exactly where it is recursively called.

Comment: Are you calling DirtySets() inside any property get accessor?

Comment: I'm sure @Maarten and Sriram are right. StackOverflowException refers to the call stack, and the only method involved here (other than system ones) is DirtySets. Therefore, one of your property getters *must* be calling DirtySets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop you have a statement that retrieves the value of a property on the class:

```
object newValue = property.GetValue(this, null);
```

As long as the type of the object is not the same as the type of `ORIGINALRECORD` all public property values are retrieved.

If one of the getters on one of the properties calls `DirtySets` you get an infinite recursion. Inside the loop you call back into `DirtySets` that starts a new loop and so on until you get a `StackOverflowException`.

To avoid this you need to ensure that either `DirtySets` is not called from the getter of any public property or that you don't retrieve the values of the properties that calls `DirtySets` in the getters.

Comment: thanks a million... Its always something obvious!          public String UpdateStatement { get { return "UPDATE " + TableName + DirtySets() + PrimaryKeyWhere; } }